# Prove that $v/\|v\|$ is the unique closest element to $v$ on the unit sphere

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $v \in V$ and $v \neq 0$. Prove that $v/\|v\|$ is the unique closest element on the unit sphere of $V$ to $v$. More precisely, prove that if $u \in V$ and $\|u\| = 1$, then
$$\left\| v - \frac{v}{\|v\|}\right\| \le \|v - u\|$$
with equality only if $u = v/\|v\|$.

So far I proved that $\|v - v/\|v\|\| = (\|v\| -1)^2$ but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Presumably you're talking about a specific norm? It's not true for general norms.

Comment: Try a geometric argument